# Use string path and perform operation on object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have several object structures that looks like:

```
this.markets[marketIndex].stands;
this.markets[marketIndex].stands[standIndex].rows;
this.markets[marketIndex].stands[standIndex].rows[rowIndex];
```

For example, when I want to delete, I need to explicitly call the whole line like so:

```
delete this.markets[marketIndex].stands[standIndex].rows;
delete this.markets[marketIndex].stands[standIndex].rows[rowIndex];
```

And I have operations to delete almost every level.

Is there a way I can create a function that handles the delete operation and when I give the path?

```
function deleteOperation(path) {
   delete this.markets[path]
}

// and call it like so:
let thePath = `[${marketIndex}].stands[${standIndex}].rows[${rowIndex}]`;

deleteOperation(thePath);
```

Or push data like this:

```
function pushData(path) {
   let something = 'test'
   this.markets[path].text = something;
}
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: what is the difference between delete (a.b.c.d) and delete a.b.c.d ? 
can you explain what do you want your argument "thePath" to look like ?

Comment: JavaScript has the features to let you do something *like* that, but it will introduce some significant complexity.

Comment: I'm curious as to what you're trying to do. Keep in mind JavaScript has a garbage collector, so there's no need to `delete` every level, just delete the highest one.

Comment: @nikoss Something like `[0].stands[2].rows[5]`

Comment: @senty isnt it easier to add delete in front of it instead of writing a function for it I mean you are writing the path anyway am I missing something ?

Comment: @robinsax I am aware of that I can delete the higher level, but I need to be able to delete different levels. What's that js feature you mentioned?

Comment: @nikoss You are right, however I am trying to move the delete logic to my state management system (ie Vuex) instead of handling it in controller; so that I can sync it to my state.

Comment: well in that case the path should be generated by there as well you are trying to isolate the logic but in this case the logic is the path you can still break things in your controller by passing wrong path to your function. Instead somehow you should create a function that generates the path on its own from id or something ( i cant say much about how since I have no clue about your app and data design) 

Again just making a function is not isolation you still keep your state logic at the contoller

Comment: @nikoss I know I can move this logic completely to vue, and it does have bunch of if conditions to check if it's deletable. Actually it's working if I don't want to move to vuex, that's why this alternative came to my mind. And to be honest I'm just curious how something like this can be achieved. My question is pretty primitive anyways, and I wanted to ask if there is a way to achieve this in javascript.

Comment: well delete operator is designed for this especially I dont think there is a simpler way then that. You also could assign undefined to the key you want to delete

Comment: @nikoss dude, delete is also pseudo. how about add that? `this.markets[thePath].test = 'test'`? The question is "is there a way to use thePath as a string to access object's path"

Comment: @senty It would have been easy if thePath is an array of key value pairs. ie
`thePath = [{node1: index}, {node2: index}]`

Comment: @AlfredAyi-bonte Interesting, can you pls elaborate on this? Like running a for loop?

Comment: @senty  Can I see your data structure for markets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use lodash's unset method: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#unset
Otherwise, you can probably reproduce something that works like this:

```
const unset = (obj, pathParts) => {
     if (pathParts.length === 1) {
         delete obj[pathParts[0]];
     } else {
         unset(obj[pathParts[0]], pathParts.slice(1));
     }
};
```

which you can call like this: unset({}, ["foo", "0", "bar"]);
You just have to use string.split if you want to have a string as an argument